# chrome remote interface ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9222

Tags: node.js, testcafe, chrome-devtools-protocol, econnrefused, chrome-remote-debugging

I am using Testcafe and it does not have direct support to access Chrome Dev Tools. My Aim is to cut the network so that I can see the error dialog in the website. This is the code that I have written. TestCafe opens at a different url
Here is the URL: http://192.168.0.123:52678/someRandomStringHere/https://abcdefgh.com/abcdefgh/

I am unable to configure the parameters for this url. FYI, the port number changes, it is not fixed.
Can someone please help me with this.

```
//Performing some actions using Testcafe here


let config = {
        offline: true,
        latency: 100,
        downloadThroughput: 750 * 1024 / 8,
        uploadThroughput: 250 * 1024 / 8
    };


    const CDP = require('chrome-remote-interface');
    const client = await CDP();
    const {Network} = client;

    await Promise.all([
        Network.enable()
    ]);
    Network.emulateNetworkConditions(config);


//Checking if the error is present or not in website after cutting the network
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take a loot at a similar question:
[How to run TestCafe tests with throttling connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55453448/how-to-run-testcafe-tests-with-throttling-connection)

Moreover, in the TestCafe repository, we have a test that emulates Network throttling: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/blob/61f3703d50ef8cc64331d09659837c52a9aae862/test/functional/fixtures/regression/gh-3929/testcafe-fixtures/index.js :

```
import { ClientFunction } from 'testcafe';

fixture `Should reconnect with bad network conditions (GH-3929)`
    .page `http://localhost:3000/fixtures/regression/gh-3929/pages/index.html`;

const getClickCount = ClientFunction(() => {
    return window.clickCount;
});

test(`Click action with bad network conditions`, async t => {
    const browserConnection = t.testRun.browserConnection;
    const browser           = browserConnection.provider.plugin.openedBrowsers[browserConnection.id];
    const client            = await browser.browserClient.getActiveClient();

    const networkConditions = {
        offline:            true,
        latency:            10,
        downloadThroughput: 100000,
        uploadThroughput:   100000
    };

    await client.Network.emulateNetworkConditions(networkConditions);

    setTimeout(() => {
        networkConditions.offline = false;

        client.Network.emulateNetworkConditions(networkConditions);
    }, 5000);

    const expectedClickCount = 10;

    for (let i = 0; i < expectedClickCount; i++)
        await t.click('button');

    const actualClickCount = await getClickCount();

    await t.expect(actualClickCount).eql(expectedClickCount);
});
```